# Pandas and glob: convert all xlsx files in folder to csv – TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob, converters

I have a folder with many xlsx files that I'd like to convert to csv files.

During my research, if found several threads about this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785824/converting-a-folder-of-excel-files-into-csv-files-merge-excel-workbooks) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934188/how-to-convert-multiple-xlsx-files-in-to-csv-using-pandas-and-globe) one. Based on this, I formulated the following code using `glob` and `pandas`:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'/Users/.../xlsx files'
excel_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.xlsx')

for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel)         # error occurs here 
    df.to_csv(out)
```

But unfortunately, I got the following error message that I could not interpret in this context and I could not figure out how to solve this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1131, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 475, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 486, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this fail on all of your Excel files?  Trying adding `print(excel)` before doing the read call to see which file it is failing on. You could also add exception handling to skip over files that fail.

Comment: Are you running on Windows with Excel installed? If so there could be an alternative approach

Comment: It seems that it fails on all excel files: The files are numbered consecutively. I added `print(excel)` as you suggested, and it randomly gave me one of those numbers. After moving this file to another folder, it failed on another random file. I tried this on >25 files. No, I am running on MacOS with Excel installed. Do you have any advice on how to deal with this?

Comment: You could try using the `openpyxl.load_workbook()` function directly (without Pandas) and pass `data_only=True`. Probably wont help but worth a try. If you had been on Windows you can automate Excel directly to load and save to CSV format, it might be possible on Mac but I've not tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. After some hours thinking and searching I realized the problem is, actually, the file. I opened it using MS Excel, and save. Alakazan, problem solved.

The file was downloaded, so i think it's a "security" error or just an error from how the file was created. xD

**EDIT:**
It's not a security problem, but actually an error from the generation of file. The correct has the double of kb the wrong file.
An solution is: if using xlrd==1.2.0 the file can be opened, you can, after doing this, call read_excel to the Book(file opened by xlrd).

```
import xlrd

# df = pd.read_excel('TabelaPrecos.xlsx')
# The line above is the same result

a = xlrd.open_workbook('TabelaPrecos.xlsx')
b = pd.read_excel(a)
```

Comment: Author's file was Kendo UI. If you are having same bug,