# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have been getting the below errors for trying to open a file with xlsx extension.

I have tried using pandas with engine as openpyxl, openpyxl library but still the error remains the same.
Code -

```
import pandas as pd 

filepath=r'C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\eclipseworkspace\demoproject\testfile1.xlsx'
readFile = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Sheet1')
readFile.head()
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
  File ".\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    readFile = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Sheet1')
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1233, in __init__   
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 522, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 420, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 533, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook    
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree       
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree 
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree 
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\smriti.rastogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'
```

Comment: OK - So that's the trace, where is your code?

Comment: It saying your using the keyword xfid, when I think you should be using xfld
(L instead of I in lowercase)

Comment: Copy the entire traceback. The interesting part is at the beginning, near `Traceback (most recent call last)`

Comment: @DarkKnight I have edited the question to include the code

Comment: @Sidney, I have not used any keyword argument except sheet_name. Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Corralien Added the entire traceback.

Comment: Hey @SmritiRastogi, Check this [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428243/pandas-and-glob-convert-all-xlsx-files-in-folder-to-csv-typeerror-init). See if this helps.

Comment: One of your style in your document is probably corrupted. Try to copy/paste your data to another blank sheet as plain text. Re-try with the new document.

Comment: @Corralien, this worked , what is xfid , haven't found any relavant links related to it.Will be helpful if you could share some resources.

Comment: The file contains invalid XML: attribute names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your very first cell (a,1) is empty or not. I noticed it needs to have a value to avoid this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when file was stored using the strict OOXML version. Unfortunately, this is not really about first cell being non-empty, but using different XML namespaces for the parts. Pandas (Openpyxl really) does not yet have the ability to detect and switch this.

Only workaround I know is open every excel file manually, and save it again. No need to add or modify content on any cell.

Source: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1796

Answer (score -1):

One of your style in your document is probably corrupted. Try to copy/paste your data to another blank sheet as plain text. Re-try with the new document.

> This worked , what is xfid , haven't found any relavant links related to it.Will be helpful if you could share some resources.

Unfortunately, there is no resources about this problem. You have to read the [source code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/tree/branch/3.0) according to the traceback to find the bug.

Comment: @JaviCarnero. How can you explain the copy/paste into another document works? About your answer: Do you mean it's not possible to read an excel file with Pandas if the first cell is empty and you don't use `skiprows` and/or `usecols`??? So please don't DV an answer when this solution works for the OP...